# ;Or statement in Regular expression not working

Tags: php

i have two html tag like :

```
$data ='<div style="background:url(img/img.jpg);color:blue"><div style="background-image:url(img/img2.jpg);color:black"></div></div>';
```

I used regular expression to get the image path like :

```
if( preg_match_all("/background-image:url\((.*?)\);/", $data, $backgroundImg) || preg_match_all("/background:url\((.*?)\);/", $data, $backgroundImg) )
```

But whenever i print the $backgroundImg it shows only the 1st one

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => background-image:url(images/background.jpg);
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => images/background.jpg
        )

)
```

how to get the 2nd one url also.

Comment: I'm surprised you get either since both your regexes expect a `;` in the pattern, but neither of the styles in the divs end with one. The other issue is that you assign the capture to the same variable in both preg functions

Comment: Seprate by braces, check this one if( (preg_match_all("/background-image:url\((.*?)\);/", $data, $backgroundImg)) || (preg_match_all("/background:url\((.*?)\);/", $backgroundImg,  $data) ) )

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$data = '<div style="background:url(img/img.jpg)"><div style="background-image:url(img/img2.jpg)"></div></div>';

preg_match_all("/background(?:-image)?:url\(([^)]+)\)/", $data, $backgroundImg);

var_export($backgroundImg);
```

Outputs:

```
array (
    0 =>
        array (
            0 => 'background:url(img/img.jpg)',
            1 => 'background-image:url(img/img2.jpg)',
        ),
    1 =>
        array (
            0 => 'img/img.jpg',
            1 => 'img/img2.jpg',
        ),
)
```

`(?:` in regex means the subpattern that does not do any capturing

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $data ='<div style="background:url(img/img.jpg)"><div style="background-image:url(img/img2.jpg)"></div></div>';

    if(preg_match_all('~\bbackground(-image)?\s*:(.*?)\(\s*(\'|")?(?<image>.*?)\3?\s*\)~i',$data,$matches)){
        $images = $matches['image'];
        print_r($images);   
    }

?>
```

**Results:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => img/img.jpg
    [1] => img/img2.jpg
)
```